# How do I get DeviceOrientationEvent and DeviceMotionEvent to work on Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, device-orientation, devicemotion

I'm trying to implement DeviceOrientationEvent and DeviceMotionEvent on my website for a 3D effect. However, the console doesn't log any info and apparently iOS 13 requires a user set permission to start doing this. I can't seem to figure out how to set it up properly.

I've done some research and this is what I found: https://github.com/w3c/deviceorientation/issues/57#issuecomment-498417027

All other methods provided online are not usable anymore sadly.

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
    console.log(event.alpha + ' : ' + event.beta + ' : ' + event.gamma);
});
```

I get the following error message:

[Warning] No device motion or orientation events will be fired until permission has been requested and granted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if ( location.protocol != "https:" ) {
location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring( window.location.protocol.length );
}
function permission () {
    if ( typeof( DeviceMotionEvent ) !== "undefined" && typeof( DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission ) === "function" ) {
        // (optional) Do something before API request prompt.
        DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
            .then( response => {
            // (optional) Do something after API prompt dismissed.
            if ( response == "granted" ) {
                window.addEventListener( "devicemotion", (e) => {
                    // do something for 'e' here.
                })
            }
        })
            .catch( console.error )
    } else {
        alert( "DeviceMotionEvent is not defined" );
    }
}
const btn = document.getElementById( "request" );
btn.addEventListener( "click", permission );
```

Use an element on your page to use as the event trigger and give it an id of "request".

This will check for https and change it if required before requesting API authorization.
Found this yesterday but do not remember the URL.

Comment: This alerts "DeviceMotionEvent is not defined" in my Safari Browser on my iPhone 6S (iOS 12). Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 22):

As of iOS 13 beta 2, you need to call DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission() to access to gyroscope or accelerometer. This will present a permission dialog prompting the user to allow motion and orientation access for this site.

Note that this will not work if you try to call it automatically when the page loads. The user needs to take some action (like tapping a button) to be able to display the dialog.

Also, the current implementation seems to require that the site have https enabled.

For more information, see [this page](https://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/#dom-deviceorientationevent-requestpermission)

Answer (score 7):

You need a click or a user gesture to call the requestPermission().
Like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function requestOrientationPermission(){
        DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()
        .then(response => {
            if (response == 'granted') {
                window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (e) => {
                    // do something with e
                })
            }
        })
        .catch(console.error)
    }
</script>

<button onclick='requestOrientationPermission();'>Request orientation permission</button>
```

Note : if you click on cancel on the permission prompt and want to test it again, you will need to quit Safari and launch it back for the prompt to come back.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but something to consider if using `DeviceMotion` on `WKWebView`.

On Xcode 13 you can use this new `WKUIDelegate`. You'll still need to request the permission as the other answers mention, but it will not prompt the user for the permission, will directly grant it.

```
@available(iOS 15, *)
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
    requestDeviceOrientationAndMotionPermissionFor origin: WKSecurityOrigin,
         initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
          decisionHandler: @escaping (WKPermissionDecision) -> Void) {
    decisionHandler(.grant)
}
```

Comment: Yes but you also need apply "DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()" in your webview.

Comment: Yes, I said “You'll still need to request the permission as the other answers mention”, but just doesn’t prompt if you do what I said

Answer (score 0):

On Xamarin iOS (Xamarin.Forms) you can inject the permission request script with the `EvaluateJavaScript` method on the WkWebView when it is ready:

```
webView.EvaluateJavaScript("DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission().then(response => { if (response == 'granted') {window.addEventListener('devicemotion', (e) => {})}}).catch(console.error)");
```

If using a custom WkWebView renderer (must implement IWKUIDelegate if this bug is still around https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203287) the script can be injected when setting the webView control in `OnElementChanged`

Example:

```
// do this when setting up the webview control in OnElementChanged
                //enable device motion sensors permission script:
                //https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/how-to-request-device-motion-and-orientation-permission-in-ios-13-74fc9d6cd140
                var source =
                "function requestSensorPermission() {" +
                "   if (typeof(DeviceMotionEvent) !== 'undefined' && typeof(DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission) === 'function') {" +
                "       DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission() .then(response => {" +
                "           if (response == 'granted') { " +
                "               window.addEventListener('devicemotion', (e) => { })" +
                "           }" +
                "       }).catch(console.error)" +
                "   }" +
                "}";
                var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(source), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);
                wkWebView.Configuration.UserContentController.AddUserScript(script);
```

Then you can call **yourCustomWebView**.EvaluateJavaScript("requestSensorPermission()") in your code behind when **yourCustomWebView** is ready.

> **EvaluateJavaScript:**
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webkit.wkwebview.evaluatejavascript?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12
>
> **Custom WkWebView Renderer:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#create-the-custom-renderer-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

There are a simple "workaround" :-)

Style:

```
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
 #orientation-tag{
  display: none;
  height: 0px;
 }
}

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
 #orientation-tag{
  display: none;
  height: 1px;
 }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="orientation-tag"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function getScreenOrientation() {

 var element = document.getElementById('orientation-tag')
 var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element)
 var value = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('height')

 if(value == '0px'){
    return 'portrait'
 }else if(value == '1px'){
    return 'landscape'
 }else{
    return 'undefined'
 }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not answer the question - the deviceorientation event is not solely for determining landscape/portrait.