# DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission() throws NotAllowedError

Tags: mobile-safari, deviceorientationevent

I have a web page that I'm loading in Safari on iOS 13.4.1.  The web page calls `DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()` and in the `.catch` following the `.then` I'm seeing this error:

> NotAllowedError: Requesting device orientation or motion access requires a user gesture to prompt

However there is no pop-up requesting permission.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: I think I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514116/how-do-i-get-deviceorientationevent-and-devicemotionevent-to-work-on-safari?rq=1 I was calling the code from onload.

Comment: D'oh, I did not see your comment/answer here, that's why I added my answer below. For the next time, you might want to provide that as an answer. HTH

Answer (score 2):

Late reply, hoping it might be useful to others.

The call `DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()` in your code must be performed as a reaction to some user gesture.

So e.g. you would show a dialog to user with a message and a button, explaining what's going to happen next. In button click handler, you hide the dialog and actually call that method.

An example of click handler is given here: https://dev.to/li/how-to-requestpermission-for-devicemotion-and-deviceorientation-events-in-ios-13-46g2 .